# Check password constraints using $watch

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have a password field to validate. The password should contain only capital letters and numbers. Use $watch to validate as the user types in the password.

Any help??

Comment: Add your code or what you have tried !

Comment: If you can't put effort on writing more detailed question, how can you expect others to put effort to answer your question? please add more details of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$watch("passwordVar", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        //your validation check logic
    });`
try like this.or Post your written code so that others can get it.